# Instant Transition - Duration Not Working?

Tags: html, css, transition

SOLUTION FOUND (added "top: 0px" to .logo-box because it needed a place to transition from)

I have a logo at the top left of my site and I want it to drop down when its div "hover-box" is hovered on, and it does. But at some point, the transition stopped taking 0.2s and is now just instant, why?

css:

```
#hover-box:hover > .logo-box {
top: 74px;
}
.logo-box {
width: 150px;
position: relative;
background-color: black;
border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is you are applying a transition to top property but it is not there in that particular class. I think you have to add top to that class.

```
.logo-box {
top: 0;
width: 150px;
position: relative;
background-color: black;
border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
top: 0px;
```

to .logo-box (non-hover)

It needs something to transition *from* :)